Programming PIC18F452 using MPLAB, LED does not turn on anywhere
As mentioned in the title, im trying to program the PIC18F452 micro-controller using a PICKit3 and MPLAB IDE 8.88 (since thats what my university requires). I have created a PCB that is a semi-devboard, that has all the pins as well as a Crystal of 4MHz soldered to the 13-14 pins, along with the 2 capacitors. But, even though my connections are all correct, the PIC doesn't light up the LEDs. Below is my code that works in Proteus, but does not work on the hardware
#include P18F452.INC

    CONFIG WDT = OFF ;Turning OFF the Watchdog Timer
    CONFIG OSC = XT
    CONFIG LVP = OFF;
    CONFIG PWRT = OFF
    CBLOCK 0x00
        SuperLoop
        OuterLoop
        InnerLoop
    ENDC

    ORG 0x00
    GOTO START
    ORG 0x20

START:
    MOVLW 0x00
    MOVWF TRISC         ; Set PORTC to output
    MOVWF TRISD
    MOVWF TRISA
    MOVWF TRISB
    GOTO MAIN

MAIN:
    MOVLW 0xFF
    MOVWF LATC
    MOVWF LATD
    MOVWF LATA
    MOVWF LATB
    GOTO MAIN

Delay1s:
    MOVLW D'4'       
    MOVWF SuperLoop     

SuperLoopLoop:
    MOVLW D'255'        
    MOVWF OuterLoop     

OuterLoopLoop:
    MOVLW D'255'        
    MOVWF InnerLoop     

InnerLoopLoop:
    DECFSZ InnerLoop, F ; Decrement InnerLoop; skip next if zero
    GOTO InnerLoopLoop  ; Repeat InnerLoop 250 times

    DECFSZ OuterLoop, F ; Decrement OuterLoop; skip next if zero
    GOTO OuterLoopLoop  ; Repeat OuterLoop 250 times

    DECFSZ SuperLoop, F ; Decrement SuperLoop; skip next if zero
    GOTO SuperLoopLoop  ; Repeat SuperLoop 250 times

    RETURN              ; Return from delay subroutine

    END

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I should also inform you, in the IDE itself, it shows that the device has been programmed when I click the program button.

Edit: For Schematics



Can you add the schematics? It might be a HW issue.

@SRomie I added the shcematics as well, please tell if theres a problem or if im just going crazy

Is that *MCLR pin tied to a GND or to a Vdd? Seems to me that when configuring PICkit3 for high-voltage programming, it need to pulse MCLR/Vpp above Vdd while programming. I'd tie it to Vdd through a 10k resistor. You've not shown DC supply connections - are you sure it is actually powered (after programming)?

@glen_geek the MCLR pin in connected to the Vpp or the first pin of the PICKit3. Im using the PICKit itself to supply power to the circuit since its a very simple LED power-on circuit. Ive set the voltage to 5V and when i check with a DMM, i get 4.96 Volts between my Vdd and Vss pins on the PIC

In your schematic it looks like you have C2 shorted to C3.

@ScottSeidman C2 and C3 are pins 17 and 18 respectively. They are both disconnected

Perhaps the real schematic would help.  We don't even know that your crystal is connected right.  If it's not, you have no clock and nothing will run.

my connections are all correct ... how do you know this?

@jsotola Im using the same schematic on Proteus, which is working in simulation. Additionally, the PCB i made, i check each and every connection for continuity, and even during the "power on" state in which the PIC should work, the connections are still continuous, but sadly, no high output on said connection

place the resistor/LED between the pin and 5 V

I am going to completely disregard the code for now because I can see a lot wrong with the "schematics".

There is no decoupling. There needs to be a capacitor close to each power input. 100n is a good value to start with.

LED current limiting resistor. You definitely need to limit the LED current as other mentioned, or you will damage the pin, LED or IC.

I would check the crystal resonator output, if it is working properly. You might not have a proper clock signal. Inspect it with an oscilloscope if you have one.


I don't have much experience with this particular microcontroller, but this is where I would start.
Let me know if this helps.

I woun't touch the Assembly code, but You have no current limiting resistor on your LED.  It's entirely possible that you damaged the LED, the port, or the output bit the first time you tried to light the LED.

It was'nt in my schematic, but when i attached the physical connection, i had 100ohm resistor attached to the ground and the led. I did have one led spark and fuse when I used a 10ohm resistor by accident. Could that fuse cause the entire PIC to be damaged? And if yes, is there anyway that i can check if its been damaged or not? Since if it was damaged, it wouldnt program either right?

@WahaajNasir You can blow out just a single pin on a mirco and have the rest of them function just fine.

@vini_i I tried different pins as well, but none seem to be able to turn on the LED

Try a different port.

@ScottSeidman I tried every single port

Well, it would seem like once upon a time, you did have 5V coming out of the port, and now you don't.  Did you change the LED after it "sparked and fused"?

As for whether it damaged the pin, the port, or the entire chip, or didn't cause any damage at all, I can't tell you.  What I can tell you is that you probably exceeded the maximum current listed on the data sheet for the chip, and that means that that particular chip is no longer guaranteed to perform to spec (by definition).  It may work fine, but it is not guaranteed to do so.

@ScottSeidman The 5V output that i got was from connecting a wire from the 5V Vdd. It sparked, i changed the LED and used a 100ohm resistor and it worked
